# Compare contents of a text file based on line number VB2008

Tags: vba

Let's say I have two text file, I will compare (based on the line numbering of text ->see below) because this is where the unique key is generated.

sample1.txt:

```
5th line -> _000_000F_01CE2577.B840E640
```

sample2.txt

```
5th line -> _000_000F_01CE2577.B840E640
```

Now here is my code:

```
            Dim FILE_NAME As String = "C:\myfiles"

            'This is to determine the number of lines in the text file
            Dim count As Integer
            count = 0

            Dim obj As StreamReader
            obj = New StreamReader(FILE_NAME)

            Do Until obj.ReadLine Is Nothing
                count = count + 1
            Loop

            '------------------------------
            'this is my computation to get the number of line -->disregard this

            Dim temp3 As Integer
            temp3 = count - 3
            '------------------------------

            obj.Close()

            'This is to read all the text in the text file
            Dim fileReader(fs) As String
            fileReader(fs) = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(FILE_NAME, _
                        System.Text.Encoding.ASCII)
```

I have stored each file in an array
Example:

```
             file[0]
             file[1]
```

Then I have to read each file and its contents, now how will i compare the line of text to each other. i believe i have to use regex.

Please give me some pointers on how to compare the line of text...

e.g. 5th line in sample1.txt == 5th line of sample2.txt

I have to know if they are the same.

Comment: What do you **exactly** want to achieve? If you only want to see if there are differences then = operator is enough. If you want to highlight differences then you might need Regex...

Comment: i have edited my question...see last line..

Comment: If you want to compare if they are the same use equal operator == (sorry I am from C# background) or .equals.

Basically, you have to iterate each line of first array and compare with the same line in the second array... (it might get tricky when you have an extra or missing line)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should do the job for you 
it will read each line in txt file , save it to an array then compare
***note:*** set paths do your 2 txt files
 
it will go out of bounds if there is less lines in file 2 than file 1. You can add a little bit of code to handle that case though.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Read_text_File()

    Dim firstFile() As String, secondFile() As String
    Dim path1 As String, path2 As String
    Dim i As Long

    path1 = "C:\ ... .txt"
    path2 = "C:\ ... .txt"

    Call fill_array(firstFile, path1)
    Call fill_array(secondFile, path2)

    For i = LBound(firstFile) To UBound(firstFile) - 1
        Debug.Print (firstFile(i) & vbTab & vbTab & vbTab & vbTab & secondFile(i))
        If StrComp(firstFile(i), secondFile(i), vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
            MsgBox "Line: " & i + 1 & "  matches "
        End If
    Next i

End Sub

Sub fill_array(ByRef arr() As String, pathToFile As String)

    Dim oFSO As New FileSystemObject
    Dim oFS As TextStream

    Dim cnt As Long
    cnt = 0

    Set oFS = oFSO.OpenTextFile(pathToFile)

    Do Until oFS.AtEndOfStream
        oFS.ReadLine
        cnt = cnt + 1
    Loop
    ReDim arr(cnt)
    Set oFS = oFSO.OpenTextFile(pathToFile)
    cnt = 0
    Do Until oFS.AtEndOfStream
        arr(cnt) = oFS.ReadLine
        cnt = cnt + 1
    Loop

    oFS.Close
    Set oFS = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: i am testing your code...seems there is an error: Variable 'firstFile' and secondfile is passed by reference before it has been assigned a value.

Comment: i have to add microsoft runtime lbrary in my project...thank you for this one. you are a lifesaver mehow..